# HTML table is out of borders in FF and IE

Tags: html, css

On this [page](http://www.jewishgiftplace.com/Jewish-Jewelry.html) in Firefox and IE if u make browser window 350px the table with products is out of borders and the scroll appears. Also the "Sort by:   Artist   Sort direction Price  " part and other elements above it are out of border too. This error does not appear in Chrome, Opera and Safari, in this browsers its adaptive for mobile screens. 
[image thats show error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPDG8.png)

Tell me please how can I make this page to be adaptive in FF and IE?
P.S. Please dont just minus, please explain what wrong with my question?

Comment: Do you use a normalizer before you load your css? If not you should use one, so your website looks the same on all PC and Browsers.

Comment: You should post the HTML and CSS to your table in order for anyone to post a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive Tables is a big problem and a lot of people (including myself) have tried many different solutions to that.

The one size fits all solution is https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw
It relies on jQuery (Javascript) and CSS to work, so it might not fit all projects, especially relying on Javascript is something I would not want to do.

Apart from that there are lots of different solutions for you to try out. Chris Coyier at CSS-Tricks wrote a great roundup some time ago: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with image that had 764px width.
I made it 100% and problem was fixed!